# Filter the search using checkbox, radio boxes etc

Tags: jquery, search

Search filter like Yelp

http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=tacos&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA&ns=1#l=p:CA:San_Francisco::[Mission,SoMa]

We are getting our search response in a rest call in XML format. We need to add filter on it so users can ofcourse, filter the results. Lets say we have below filters:

Checkboxes -

```
Solved
Unsolved
Most Liked
```

Radio buttons-

```
A month ago
A week ago
A day ago
```

So, a user can select multiple check boxes and any one of radios, and the results on right side should be filtered based upon these. I don't want to make and ajax calls, we will be getting the data in XML as I mentioned and then want to filter it based upon the choices user selected. Please suggest.

Comment: Show us some of your code. What have you tried?

Comment: This is pretty vague. Posting _some_ of your code would help.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example, but I'm not sure how exactly you want it to function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").click(function () {
        var selected_cat = $('input[name=cat]:checked').map(function (_, el) {
            return $(el).val();
        }).get();

        var checked_time = $("input[name=time]:checked").val();

        if (selected_cat.length > 0 && checked_time !== undefined) {
            $("#str").html("some_search_script.php?cat="+selected_cat.join() + "&time="+checked_time);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6QDJM/

Comment: Basically, i m looking for a search filter just like Yelo  http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=tacos&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA&ns=1#l=p:CA:San_Francisco::[Mission,SoMa]